# How to find the standard error of the mean?

Tags: r, statistics, standard-error

Is there any command to find the standard error of the mean in R?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

There's the [plotrix](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/plotrix/html/00Index.html) package with has a built-in function for this: [std.error](http://rss.acs.unt.edu/Rdoc/library/plotrix/html/std.error.html)

Answer (score 187):

The standard error is just the standard deviation divided by the square root of the sample size. So you can easily make your own function:

```
> std <- function(x) sd(x)/sqrt(length(x))
> std(c(1,2,3,4))
[1] 0.6454972
```

Answer (score 106):

The standard error (SE) is just the standard deviation of the sampling distribution. The variance of the sampling distribution is the variance of the data divided by N and the SE is the square root of that. Going from that understanding one can see that it is more efficient to use variance in the SE calculation. The `sd` function in R already does one square root (code for `sd` is in R and revealed by just typing "sd"). Therefore, the following is most efficient.

```
se <- function(x) sqrt(var(x)/length(x))
```

Comment: Interestingly, your function and Ian's are nearly identically fast. I tested them both 1000 times against 10^6 million rnorm draws (not enough power to push them harder than that). Conversely, plotrix's function was always slower than even the slowest runs of those two functions - but it also has a lot more going on under the hood.

Comment: That is likely because the advantage of John's function avoids one function call and calculating the square root of a single number. If there is any advantage at all, it is at very small n.

Comment: Not just likely but true... I did timing runs of rnorm(5) but did 5e4 executions of the se command.  My version takes about 2.5s while the one with two sqrts takes about 2.8.  A small speed up indeed.
(I did several runs and am reporting a rounded average)

Comment: Note that `stderr` is a function name in `base`.

Comment: That's a very good point. I typically use se. I have changed this answer to reflect that.

Comment: Tom, NO `stderr` does NOT calculate standard error it displays `display aspects. of connection`

Comment: @forecaster Tom didn't say `stderr` calculates the standard error, he was warning that this name is used in base, and John originally named his function `stderr` (check the edit history...).

Comment: I believe the second version is not a good idea because for `na.rm = TRUE` it gives incorrect results as `length(x)` does not account for removed `NA`s.

Comment: Correct @Quasimodo. I've removed the erroneous function. Now the answer is just back to it's old simple self. The arandomlypickedname answer is correct for a more general case.

Answer (score 70):

A version of John's answer above that removes the pesky NA's:

```
stderr <- function(x, na.rm=FALSE) {
  if (na.rm) x <- na.omit(x)
  sqrt(var(x)/length(x))
}
```

Comment: Note that there is an existing function called `stderr` in the `base` package that does something else, so it might be better to chose another name for this one, e.g. `se`

Answer (score 7):

The [sciplot](https://cran.r-project.org/package=sciplot) package has the built-in function `se(x)`

Answer (score 4):

As I'm going back to this question every now and then and because this question is old, I'm posting a benchmark for the most voted answers.

Note, that for @Ian's and @John's answers I created another version. Instead of using `length(x)`, I used `sum(!is.na(x))` (to avoid NAs).
I used a vector of 10^6, with 1,000 repetitions.

```
library(microbenchmark)

set.seed(123)
myVec <- rnorm(10^6)

IanStd <- function(x) sd(x)/sqrt(length(x))

JohnSe <- function(x) sqrt(var(x)/length(x))

IanStdisNA <- function(x) sd(x)/sqrt(sum(!is.na(x)))

JohnSeisNA <- function(x) sqrt(var(x)/sum(!is.na(x)))

AranStderr <- function(x, na.rm=FALSE) {
  if (na.rm) x <- na.omit(x)
  sqrt(var(x)/length(x))
}

mbm <- microbenchmark(
  "plotrix" = {plotrix::std.error(myVec)},
  "IanStd" = {IanStd(myVec)},
  "JohnSe" = {JohnSe(myVec)},
  "IanStdisNA" = {IanStdisNA(myVec)},
  "JohnSeisNA" = {JohnSeisNA(myVec)},
  "AranStderr" = {AranStderr(myVec)}, 
  times = 1000)

mbm
```

Results:

```
Unit: milliseconds
       expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq      max neval cld
    plotrix 10.3033 10.89360 13.869947 11.36050 15.89165 125.8733  1000   c
     IanStd  4.3132  4.41730  4.618690  4.47425  4.63185   8.4388  1000 a  
     JohnSe  4.3324  4.41875  4.640725  4.48330  4.64935   9.4435  1000 a  
 IanStdisNA  8.4976  8.99980 11.278352  9.34315 12.62075 120.8937  1000  b 
 JohnSeisNA  8.5138  8.96600 11.127796  9.35725 12.63630 118.4796  1000  b 
 AranStderr  4.3324  4.41995  4.634949  4.47440  4.62620  14.3511  1000 a  


library(ggplot2)
autoplot(mbm)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Remembering that the mean can also by obtained using a linear model, regressing the variable against a single intercept, you can use also the `lm(x~1)` function for this!

Advantages are:

- You obtain immediately confidence intervals with `confint()`
- You can use tests for various hypothesis about the mean, using for example `car::linear.hypothesis()`
- You can use more sophisticated estimates of the standard deviation, in case you have some heteroskedasticity, clustered-data, spatial-data etc, see package `sandwich`

```r
## generate data
x <- rnorm(1000)

## estimate reg
reg <- lm(x~1)
coef(summary(reg))[,"Std. Error"]
#> [1] 0.03237811

## conpare with simple formula
all.equal(sd(x)/sqrt(length(x)),
          coef(summary(reg))[,"Std. Error"])
#> [1] TRUE

## extract confidence interval
confint(reg)
#>                   2.5 %    97.5 %
#> (Intercept) -0.06457031 0.0625035
```

<sup>Created on 2020-10-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function stat.desc from pastec package.

```
library(pastec)
stat.desc(x, BASIC =TRUE, NORMAL =TRUE)
```

you can find more about it from here:
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pastecs/versions/1.3.21/topics/stat.desc