# Using R program to make scatter plots with standard errors

Tags: r, plot

I'm really new to R and I want to use it to make some graphs. So I have this sample data, 
Scores for Day 1

Comment: Why are you deleting all the contents of your questions?? If you want to delete a question, you can flag a moderator to do it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to include the average in the dataset, you can easily access it using `mean()`

Recreate the dataset;

```
dataset <- read.table(text="One Two Three   Four    Five    Six
    4   6   10  10  6   4
    5   7   5   10  4   5
    4   8   4   2   4   2
    6   4   8   5   3   3
    7   5   8   6   4   5
    7   5   8   8   7   5
    8   5   9   9   8   5
    4   5   4   3   8   7
    6   6   4   5   4   2
    4   6   7   7   8   3", head=TRUE)
```

Get the average of game one;

```
mean(dataset$One)
```

As for the standard error please see this question; [In R, how to find the standard error of the mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676554/in-r-how-to-find-the-standard-error-of-the-mean)